# Pesquisa na query retornada

Tags: php, javascript

Estou a criar a minha tabela com paginação desta forma e com possibilidade de pesquisa com um `input`:

```
<?php 
$itens_por_pagina = 5;
$pagina = intval($_GET['pagina']);
if (!$pagina) {
    $pc = "0";
} else {
    $pc = $pagina;
}
$inicio = $pc - 0;
$inicio = $inicio * $itens_por_pagina;
$query = "SELECT A.id, A.nome, B.nome AS Nomes FROM raddb.usuarios AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.niveis_acessos AS B ON B.id = A.niveis_acesso_id ORDER BY Nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $itens_por_pagina";
$result = $conn->query($query) or die($conn->error);
$produto = $result->fetch_assoc();
$num = $result->num_rows;
$num_total = $conn->query("SELECT A.id, A.nome, B.nome AS Nomes FROM raddb.usuarios AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.niveis_acessos AS B ON B.id = A.niveis_acesso_id ORDER BY Nome ASC")->num_rows;
$num_paginas = ceil($num_total / $itens_por_pagina);
?>
<div id="employee_table">
    <h1>Utilizadores</h1>
    <?php if ($num > 0) { ?>
        <table class="table table-responsive lista-clientes">
            <thead>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="Filter"></span><input type="text" class="input-search" alt="lista-clientes"/>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Nível de Acesso</th>
                <th>Ações</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php do{ ?>

                <td><?php echo $produto["nome"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $produto["Nomes"]; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" name="view" id="<?php echo $produto["id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm view_data"/>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" id="<?php echo $produto["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-dander btn-sm delete"/>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php } while ($produto = $result->fetch_assoc()); ?>
            </tbody>

        </table>

        <nav>
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                    <a href="?pagina=0" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php
                for ($i = 0; $i < $num_paginas; $i++) {
                    $estilo = "";
                    if ($pc == $i) {
                        $estilo = "class=\"active\"";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <li <?php echo $estilo; ?> ><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i + 1; ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="?pagina=<?php echo $num_paginas - 1; ?>" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

`input` de pesquisa:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="Filter"></span><input type="text" class="input-search" alt="lista-clientes"/>
```

Função para pesquisar nas colunas da minha tabela:

```
$(function(){
    $(".input-search").keyup(function(){
        //pega o css da tabela 
        var tabela = $(this).attr('alt');
        if( $(this).val() != ""){
            $("."+tabela+" tbody>tr").hide();
            $("."+tabela+" td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show();
        } else{
            $("."+tabela+" tbody>tr").show();
        }
    }); 
});
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "contains-ci": function(elem, i, match, array) {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
});
```

Até aqui tudo funciona bem. Agora o que pretendo é, que a minha tabela retorna 5 linhas em cada página, e quando pesquiso no `input` só faz a pesquisa nessas 5 linhas e pretendia que fizesse a pesquisa em todas as linhas que a query retorna.

Comment: Vc utiliza algum plugin para fazer a paginação ou a tabela?

Comment: @Sam não, só usei esse código

Comment: Rapaz, o problema é que a paginação só gera no HTML as linhas da página, ou seja, as outras linhas das outras páginas não existem no HTML, por isso não tem como encontrá-las. Talvez vc devesse usar o [Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4) que já vem com paginação e filtro tudo junto.